# React UseEffect render infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I seem to have an infinite loop in my code but I can't seem to see where, I usually see this if I am setting the state of something that is a dependency of useEffect but here the two variables (values / items) are completely seperate.

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './style.css';
import MyComponent from './MyComponent.js';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <MyComponent />
    </div>
  );
}
```

MyComponent.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const MyComponent = ({ values = [] }) => {

  console.log('MyComponent Reloaded');
  const [items, setItems] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadItems = () => {
      //setItems([]);   //why does this cause infinite render loop?
    };

    loadItems();
  }, [values]);

  return <></>;
};

export default MyComponent;
```

Why does this cause a render loop?

I have an example build  [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hswrzr?file=src%2FMyComponent.js,src%2FApp.js) (Uncomment the commented line to begin render loop)

Comment: Your `useEffect` runs when you change `values`. You change `values` in that `useEffect`.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Can you explain where I am changing values? The only place I set it is in the props

Comment: Oh sorry, I was wrong. You are creating new `values` in each render. Remember that `[] !== []` so `useEffect` detect this a achange

Comment: So useState will cause a re-render, even if the state being changed isn't used in the output of the function?

Comment: Yes, change of state will always cause a re-render

Comment: You can use `useRef` to preserve values

Answer (score 1):

You need to introduce the default values of the props the right way:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const MyComponent = ({ values }) => {
  console.log('MyComponent Reloaded');
  const [items, setItems] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(values)
    const loadItems = () => {
      setItems([]);
    };

    loadItems();
  }, [values]);

  return <></>;
};

MyComponent.defaultProps = {
  values: []
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible bugs in the code:

- According to your code, `values` variable is created every time, when checked with the previous `values` variable it is not same. So it causes infinite loop.

  - To fix this use default props.

    ```
    const MyComponent = ({ values }) => {
     ...

    MyComponent.defaultProps = {
      values: []
    }
    ```
- As in your question,this line causes you the infinite loop

  ```
     //setItems([]);
  ```

  - To overcome this

    Add `items` dependency along with `values`, so that both values are watched before re-rendering.

    ```
    useEffect(() => {
    console.log(values)
    const loadItems = () => {
      setItems([]);
    };

    loadItems();
    }, [values,items]);
    ```